# Filtering out elements before they are appended?

Tags: d3.js

The following code block, which comes from the [D3 documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#data):

```
var matrix = [
  ["A", "B"],
  ["A", "B"]
];

var tr = d3.select("body").append("table").selectAll("tr")
  .data(matrix)
  .enter().append("tr");

var td = tr.selectAll("td")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter().append("td")
  .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

...outputs this markup:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Could this be adapted (using `.filter` maybe?) to output:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/24ma13wg/pen/yVVWjX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use filter, but my solution here is for *after* they are appended.

It can be done in a single step, but two steps is more didactic:

```
var filtered = d3.selectAll("td").filter(function(d){
    return d=="A"
});
```

This returns a selection of all `<td>` with A. Then, we set the `rowspan` of the first one according to the total number of `<td>`s, and delete all the rest:

```
filtered.each(function(d, i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        d3.select(this).attr("rowspan", filtered.nodes().length)
    } else {
        d3.select(this).remove()
    }
});
```

With this rule, we can have an even longer array, like:

```
var matrix = [
    ["A", "B"],
    ["A", "B"],
    ["A", "B"],
    ["A", "B"]
];
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var matrix = [
    ["A", "B"],
    ["A", "B"],
    ["A", "B"],
    ["A", "B"]
];

var tr = d3.select("body").append("table").selectAll("tr")
    .data(matrix)
    .enter().append("tr");

var td = tr.selectAll("td")
    .data(function(d) {
        return d;
    })
    .enter().append("td")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d;
    });

var filtered = d3.selectAll("td").filter(function(d) {
    return d == "A"
});
filtered.each(function(d, i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        d3.select(this).attr("rowspan", filtered.nodes().length)
    } else {
        d3.select(this).remove()
    }
})
```

```css
tr, td {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```